# Spring Framework. Issues with accessing SOAP Webservice

Tags: spring, soap-client

Im trying to access the SOAP webservice. from the client UI. Im getting the below error message while accessing the webservice. Im not sure what needs to be done to fix this issue. When I put debug points in the client code and run, the same code works fine and Im able to access the webservice fine in debug mode. Please Assist.

```
DEBUG http-8080-3 org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher - Endpoint invocation resulted in exception - responding with Fault
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapEnvelopeException: Could not access envelope: Unable to create envelope from given source: ; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source: 
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getEnvelope(SaajSoapMessage.java:90)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage.getSoapHeader(AbstractSoapMessage.java:41)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher.handleHeaders(SoapMessageDispatcher.java:102)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher.handleRequest(SoapMessageDispatcher.java:92)
at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:205)
at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:168)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source: 
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.Saaj13Implementation.getEnvelope(Saaj13Implementation.java:169)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getEnvelope(SaajSoapMessage.java:86)
... 24 more
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
at com.icl.saxon.IdentityTransformer.transform(IdentityTransformer.java:92)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(Unknown Source)
... 29 more
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
at com.icl.saxon.ContentEmitter.startElement(ContentEmitter.java:124)
at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.RejectDoctypeSaxFilter.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.icl.saxon.IdentityTransformer.transform(IdentityTransformer.java:90)
... 30 more
```

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ and where is your code?